# Get the previous element of a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, listiterator

I need to get the previous element of a LinkedHashMap. 
I tried using the ListIterator because it has the previous() method. But the problem is ListIterator needs a List not a set.

```
ListIterator<Entry<String, Integer>> it = (ListIterator<Entry<String, Integer>>) unitsItems.entrySet().iterator();
```

I have to transform my entrySet into a list. So I tried this :

```
List entryList= new ArrayList (unitsItems.entrySet());
     ListIterator<Entry<String, Integer>> it = (ListIterator<Entry<String, Integer>>) entryList.iterator();
```

I got this error:

```
java.util.ArrayList$Itr cannot be cast to java.util.ListIterator
```

Can anyone tell me the correct way to transform the set to a list and then use it in ListIterator?
Thank you.

Comment: by `Map#entrySet()` you get `Set` *view* of entries, which doesn't provide `ListIterator`, only `Iterator`

Comment: Try `entryList.listIterator()`.

Comment: @Thomas: It works! I didn't notice that I used iterator(). 
Please write the answer and I will accept it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per request: Since you already have the list `entryList` you just need to call `listIterator()` on it to get what you want.

Btw, I'd add the generic type to the list as well: `List<Entry<String, Integer>> = new ArrayList<>(unitsItems.entrySet());`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 8, you can do this:

```
@Test
public void obtainListIterator() {

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> test = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    test.put("1", "a");
    test.put("2", "a");
    test.put("3", "a");

    ListIterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> listIterator = 
                                                         test
                                                           .entrySet()
                                                           .stream()
                                                           .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                                           .listIterator();

    assertThat(listIterator.next().getKey()).isEqualTo("1");
    assertThat(listIterator.previous().getKey()).isEqualTo("1");
}
```

However, the answer given by @Thomas is better than mine:

```
ListIterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> listIterator = new LinkedList(test.entrySet()).listIterator();
```

Comment: That's only by chance that the new list collected is ordered like the original linkedHashMap, since the specification does not guarantee that the entrySet() is in any particular order.

Comment: I don't think so @A.Rama, because `LinkedHashMap` has its own implementation of `entrySet`. It creates a `LinkedEntrySet` to store the entries

Answer (score 0):

Using `entrySet()` is wrong since it's a method of `HashMap` and thus it does not contain any notion of list (thus your problems).

As you can see from the [sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#LinkedHashMap) the linked list is implemented directly at the `LinkedHashMap` level.

That means that to do what you need (since the API do not supply a way) you'll need to subclass the `LinkedHashMap` and do it yourself.